# Accessing void pointers in Python (using SWIG or something else)

Tags: python, pointers, swig, void

I've been trying to use SWIG to wrap around a simple library that uses ioctl() to populate a structure like the following:

```
struct data
{
  header* hdr;
  void* data;
  size_t len;
};
```

**data** is a pointer to a buffer, **len** is the length of that buffer.

I'm unable to figure out how to convert **data** to a Python string (or array). Furthermore, I need a way to free that buffer in the destructor. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "or something else" in the Q's title -- if you choose to use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes), you can represent a `void*` with `c_void_p` (one of ctypes' [fundamental data types](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#fundamental-data-types), and access functions such as `free` and `memcpy` from the C runtime library (as long as the latter's available as a DLL / .so dynamic library, but that's true pretty widely these days).  To get a mutable character buffer into which you can `memcpy` the data, use [create_string_buffer](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.create_string_buffer).

Of course you could alternatively use the Python C API -- [PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize](http://docs.python.org/c-api/bytearray.html#PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize) is what you'd use in this case to make a byte array copy from your `void*` and length (and of course you'd call `free` directly, when appropriate, since it's just C code anyway).

Another possibility to consider is [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), a Python-like language designed to write Python extensions and such that the Cython compiler can generate compilable C code from Cython sources - in Cython, your `struct` would be:

```
cdef struct data:
    void* hdr
    void* data
    unsigned int* len
```

assuming you don't want to go to the trouble of declaring `header` (i.e., that only `data` and `len` matter to you here) -- `size_t`, I believe, is not part of Cython at this time (I could be wrong, they do keep adding stuff;-), but `unsigned int` can probably do.

Sorry, it's been too long since I used SWIG in earnest (what with all these excellent alternatives) -- I'd have skipped the Q were it not for that tempting "or something else" clause in the title;-).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm currently loiking into Cython, looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

swig provides a module named 'cdata.i'. You should include this in the interface definition file.

Once you include this, it gives two functions cdata() and memmove(). Given a void * and the length of the binary data, cdata() converts it into a string type of the target language. memmove() is the reverse. given a string type, it will copy the contents of the string(including embedded null bytes) into the C void* type.

Handling binary data becomes much simple with this module. I hope this is what you need.