# SWIG Support of void * C return types

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I have a C function in my SWIG interface file (included from a header file) that currently returns a char * that SWIG uses to generate a String Java return type for fetchFromRow method. I'm wondering if I change the return to a void * on the C side, what will SWIG do on the Java side? The C fetchFromRow function returns a structure (sockaddr_in), String or int. How can I setup my SWIG interface file to support this?  Is there a way to make the generated Java fetchFromRow have a return type of Object so that I can just cast on the Java side?

C Code:

```
extern char *
fetchFromRow(struct row_t *r_row,
        type_t type);

extern void *
fetchFromRow(struct row_t *r_row,
        type_t type);
```

When I generate the method using the void * in the header file (included in SWIG interface file), I get a java method with a SWIGTYPE_p_void return type.  Any ideas on how to handle that?

Swig File:

```
%module Example
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "stdint.i"
%include "arrays_java.i"
void setPhy_idx(uint32_t value);
%include "arrays_java.i"
void setId(unsigned char *value);
%{
#include "Example1.h"
#include "Example2.h"
#include "Example3.h"
#include "Example4.h"
%}
%rename setLogFile setLogFileAsString;
%inline %{
void setLogFileAsString(const char *fn) {
  FILE *f = fopen(fn, "w");
  setLogFile(f);
}
%}
%typemap(jstype) void* "java.lang.Object"
%typemap(javaout) void* {
  long cPtr = $jnicall;
  Object result = null;
  if (type == type_t.TYPE_CATEGORY) {
    result = void2int8(cPtr);
  }
  return result;
}

%newobject fetch(struct result_row_t *result_row, type_t type, int32_t *length);
%inline %{

uint8_t void2int8(jlong v) {
  return (intptr_t)v;
}

%}
%apply char * { unsigned char * };
%apply char * { const void * }
%apply int32_t { int32_t * }
int createKey(const void* secret, int secret_len, const sdr_id_t *id, unsigned char key[20], int key_len);
session_t* createSession(const char* addr, int ort, const char *ddr, int rt, const der_id_t *id, unsigned char key[20], int key_len); 
%apply int32_t *OUTPUT { int32_t *length }
%ignore createKey;
%ignore setLogFile;
%ignore ecreateSession;
%include "Example1.h"
%include "Example2.h"
%include "Example3.h"
%include "Example4.h"
%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("Example");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}
```

Java Code to call fetch:

```
{
   //only type_t param shown here for simplicity
   Object category = Example.fetch(result_row, type_t.TYPE_CATEGORY, length);
   System.out.println("category=" + aLevel.toString());
   System.out.println("category=" + ((Short)aLevel).intValue());
   System.out.println("category=" + ((Short)aLevel).toString());
   //all 3 Sys outs show same value but when called again each show same value but different than the first execution
}
```

C Code Wrapper that I'm attempting to Replace with SWIG.  This use to be called from Java but now I'm trying to call fetch directly (pseudo code):

```
char *
wrapFetch(struct row_t *result_row, type_t type)
{
int8_t *int8_valp = NULL;
switch (attribute) {
 case TYPE_CATEGORY:

        int8_valp = fetch(
                result_row, attribute, &length);
        if (length > 0 && int8_valp != NULL) {
            snprintf(smallbuf, sizeof(smallbuf), "%u", *int8_valp);
            return strdup(smallbuf);
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a dupe of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345354/accessing-void-pointers-in-python-using-swig-or-something-else

Comment: it's slightly different.  Its about supporting the void C return type

Comment: It's tricky, but do-able I think. Basically you need a mapping between `type_t`s and the "real" type they're representing in order to make the cast's on the Java side viable. I have an example of something similar for Python that I'll hopefully be able to convert to Java this weekend.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia - I don't think this is a duplicate since in that case `void*` is being used as a buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be easier if you defined a type hierarchy for the return types, and used the base class as the return type for `fetchFromRow`. (It turns out that solution isn't as easy as I originally thought it would be and there's even [an example in the documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#adding_downcasts)! [This question also applies to Java+SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458025/how-to-properly-downcast-in-c-sharp-with-a-swig-generated-interface)) As it stands though doing what you asked is possible, I've made a simpler example to illustrate the important points.

The example I'm working with here has a simple interface, in `test.h` (both the declarations and the definitions to keep things simpler here):

```
struct type1 {
  type1(int foo) : foo(foo) {}
  int foo;
};

struct type2 {
  type2(double bar) : bar(bar) {}
  double bar;
};

// TYPE3 is int32_t, TYPE4 is const char*

typedef enum { TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3, TYPE4 } type_t;

void* fetch(type_t type) {
  switch(type) {
  case TYPE1:
    return new type1(101);
  case TYPE2:
    return new type2(1.111);
  case TYPE3:
    return (void*)(-123); // One way of returning int32_t via void*!
  case TYPE4:
    return (void*)("Hello world"); // Cast because not const void*
  default:
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

Here we have four different types, paired with an `enum` value. These were picked for simplicity. They could be anything you want, provided you have a suitable typemap that can be applied. (If you want `sockaddr_in` specifically then apply the typemap from [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142028/how-to-map-sockaddr-in-c-structure-to-java-using-swig/8148744#8148744) about wrapping `sockaddr_in` specifically).

There's also a function `fetch` which creates one of the types and returns it via `void *`. This illustrates what you asked about in the question. The tricky thing with `fetch` is that SWIG has no direct way of inferring what was behind the `void*` pointer before it got returned. We need to give SWIG a way of knowing more specifically what the type is, using our higher level knowledge about the meaning of the `type_t` parameter.

To wrap this we need a SWIG interface file, `test.i` which begins with the usual module stuff:

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}
```

In order to wrap our `fetch` function we need to find a sensible way of exposing the closest thing to `void*` on the Java side. In this instance I think `java.lang.Object` is a good choice for the return type and it approximates the `void*` reasonably well here.

```
%typemap(jstype) void* "java.lang.Object"
```

This sets up what the return type from `fetch` on the Java side will be. (We've not changed the return type of the generated JNI intermediary using `%typemap(jtype)` though, this will still default to `long` as before).

Next we need to write another typemap to specify how the result of the actual call is going to get converted into the type we said the call would return on the Java side:

```
%typemap(javaout) void* {
  long cPtr = $jnicall;
  Object result = null;
  if (type == type_t.TYPE1) {
    result = new type1(cPtr, $owner);
  }
  else if (type == type_t.TYPE2) {
    result = new type2(cPtr, $owner);
  }
  else if (type == type_t.TYPE3) {
    result = void2int(cPtr);
    // could also write "result = new Integer(void2int(cPtr));" explicitly here
  }
  else if (type == type_t.TYPE4) {
    result = void2str(cPtr);
  }

  return result;
}

%newobject fetch(type_t type);
```

Here we create a Java object, of the appropriate the SWIG proxy types, or call a helper function we'll see shortly. We decide which to type to use by looking at the `type_t` that was used in the call. (I'm not 100% happy about referring to this type by name, i.e. `type` directly but there doesn't seem to be a better way of gaining access to the parameters a function was called with inside a `javaout` typemap)

The second argument to each of the constructors, seen here as `$owner` is important for memory management, it states who owns the allocation and we'd like to transfer ownership to Java to avoid leaking it. Its value is determined by the `%newobject` directive.

We need a helper function to convert the `void*` to more meaningful types for the `int32_t` and `String` cases. We supply this with `%inline` to ask SWIG to wrap and define it at the same time:

```
%inline %{
int32_t void2int(jlong v) {
  return (intptr_t)v;
}

const char *void2str(jlong v) {
  return (const char*)v;
}
%}
```

I used `jlong` here because on the Java side of the interface all pointers are represented as `long`. It ensures the functions are exactly compatible with what the JNI call is returning, without losing precision (on some platforms it's possible that `jlong` might be a `long long`). Basically these functions exist to make the conversion from the generic (`void*`) to the specific on the C side with as little manual work as possible. SWIG handles all of the types for us here.

Finally we finish up with `%include` for the header file (we want to wrap it all so that's the simplest way) and some code to cause the library to get loaded automatically:

```
%include "test.h"

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("test");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}
```

I tested this wrapping by compiling:

```
swig -Wall -java -c++ test.i
javac *.java 
g++ -Wall -Wextra test_wrap.cxx -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux/ -o libtest.so
```

and running the following Java code to "exercise" it a bit.

```
public class main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Object o1 = test.fetch(type_t.TYPE1);
    Object o2 = test.fetch(type_t.TYPE2);
    Object o3 = test.fetch(type_t.TYPE3);
    Object o4 = test.fetch(type_t.TYPE4);

    if (!(o1 instanceof type1)) {
      System.out.println("Wrong type - o1");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("o1.getFoo(): " + ((type1)o1).getFoo());
    }

    if (!(o2 instanceof type2)) {
      System.out.println("Wrong type - o2");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("o2.getFoo(): " + ((type2)o2).getBar());
    }

    if (!(o3 instanceof Integer)) {
      System.out.println("Wrong type - o3");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("o3.intValue(): " + ((Integer)o3).intValue());
    }

    if (!(o4 instanceof String)) {
      System.out.println("Wrong type - o4");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("o4: " + (String)o4);
    }
  }
}
```

You can always recreate the whole example from the code shown here, `test.i` is shown and discussed sequentially, but for convenience I've also put a copy of [test.i on my site](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ajw/polyret.i).

Comment: I reviewed this answer again and just wondered if there is anyway to handle the void* without modifying the header files?  I'm assuming not...just thought I'd ask.

Comment: @c12 - the answer I gave which used the javaout and jstype typemaps doesn't need any modification to the header files to work. The header file I showed was just my guess as to what a simplified version of your header file might look like and gave me something to test against. The types, `enum` and implementation of `fetch` can be pretty much anything you like though.

Comment: couldn't you also just map void* through the SWIG %apply to a byte array and then in Java just handle the byte array and convert it to String, Integer..etc?  Not sure of the implementation of that, but it sounds doable...thoughts?

Comment: @c12 - that would be feasible, but it seems like a lot of work to me given that we can ask SWIG to wrap all of the types for us and just write a tiny bit of code to channel the return into the right one. Doing it the other way would require writing a large chunk of Java for every type you want to support and make them copies of, not references to the original C or C++ types. Portably taking a `byte[]` which happened to be an `int32_t` in C++ and making that into an Integer in Java would be quite tricky I suspect. SWIG hides all this. The JNI just to get the `int` into `byte[]` would be tedious

Comment: I agree with you.  The reason why I proposed this is I know Java and SWIG is brand new to me.  I'll attempt to get your suggestion to work as it's the cleanest solution.

Comment: One thing I don't fully understand is how the new Object creation code changes if the C fetch function returns a int16_t, int8_t, int32_t or char type (i.e. result = new type1(cPtr, $owner).  Above type1 is a structure that SWIG will generate a wapper for and that makes sense. I can't do a result = new Integer or new String as their constructors don't support (cPtr, $owner).  How would you cast the int16_t, int8_t, int32_t or char types?

Comment: @c12 - I see exactly what you're getting at there now. I've added to my example to show how you might do this for `int32_t`  and `const char*`, which are slightly trickier than the examples I showed because they wrap to existing Java types. The simplest non-intrusive way of making that possible in the javaout typemap is to get SWIG to wrap a little bit of extra C for our Java interface. I basically added `void2str` and `void2int` to help with this, the rest is just calling them.

Comment: the chars/Strings are coming through perfectluy.  Most of the void*'s return types are uint8_t and uint16_t.  So, I've added the following to handle them %inline %{uint8_t void2int(jlong v) {return (intptr_t)v;} and uint16_t void2int(jlong v) {return (intptr_t)v;} and then cast them to Short and Integer respectively on the java side. Issue is the uint8_t and uint16_t values are not correct on the java System.outs. One value should be 10 consistently but its coming through as 32, 160, 82. I think I have a bug in the inlines for uint8_t and uint16_t, should those be changed?

Comment: @c12 - you need to give them a different name for the different return types. I'm surprised `uint8_t void2int(jlong v);` `uint16_t void2int(jlong v);` compile - call them something like `uint8_t void2uint8(jlong v);` and `uint8_t void2uint16(jlong v);` and make sure you call the right one on for the right type on the Java side.

Comment: that was a typo on my part. Currently, I only have a uint8_t void2int8(jlong v) {return (intptr_t)v;} to test. Each time I call the fetch(type_t type) api, I get a different value returned to java for the same attribute. For example: 128, 32, 16.  The value is wrong in all cases but it should be consistently wrong instead of changing values. Is the cast of return (intptr_t)v; proper for a uint8_t data type? I copied an example version of my SWIG file in the original question to see if there is something that is conflicting with the changes you proposed.

Comment: not sure it will help but I added my java code and the old C wrapper function (wrapFetch) that I'm trying to replace.  the wrapFetch C function returns the proper value for category but I'd like to eliminate the extra C layer and go straight to the real C API.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5511/discussion-between-c12-and-awoodland)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I like to use for tough cases like this one is to (a) simplify the C interface to get better results from SWIG, and (b) bring the complexity back in the target language as a wrapper to the simplified C functions.

In your case, I would add two additional functions to the C API:

```
char* fetchFromRowString(struct row_t *r_row);
int fetchFromRowInt(struct row_t *r_row);
```

These would be a piece of cake for SWIG to handle. Then on the Java side you can recreate the original `fetchFromRow()`, where the implementation calls the String or Int version of the C function depending on the type, and finally returns the result as Object.

Good luck.